# Unable to list the another table data using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

### Edit: [Solved] - Did not load the model.

I'm able to display the list of groups fetched from the table. But unable to display the list of centers.

I'm unable to find where I have made an error.

When I uncomment the `$data['allcenters']`, I just get an empty page. But when I remove the line, the page displays fine but without the list of centers.

The table name of groups is user_groups.
The table name of centers is institute_data.

The code is as below:

Controller: (user_data.php)

```
function add_new(){
$logged_in=$this->session->userdata('logged_in');
if($logged_in['su']!="1"){
exit('Permission denied');
return; 
}       
    $data['title']="Add User";

    //get the list of the groups
    $data['allgroups'] = $this->group_model->get_allgroups();

    //get the list of all centers
    $data['allcenters'] = $this->centers_model->get_allcenters();
    //Page is displayed when the above code is commented. 
    //On inserting the above line, the page is just blank

    $this->load->view($this->session->userdata('web_view').'/header',$data);
    $this->load->view($this->session->userdata('web_view').'/add_user',$data);
    $this->load->view($this->session->userdata('web_view').'/footer',$data);
}
```

Model (centers_model.php):

```
function get_allcenters(){
    $query = $this->db->get("institute_data");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
    }
```

Model (group_model.php):

```
function get_allgroups(){
    $query = $this->db->get("user_group");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
    }
```

View (add_user.php)

```
<?php print_r($allcenters); ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Center </label>
    <select class="form-control" name="centers">
    <?php foreach($allcenters as $key => $center){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $center['su_institute_id']; ?>"><?php echo $center['organization_name']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
 </div>

<?php print_r($allgroups); ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Group </label>
    <select class="form-control" name="user_group">
    <?php foreach($allgroups as $key => $group){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $group['gid']; ?>"><?php echo $group['group_name']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I have solved the problem.

I have not loaded the model in the __construct() function.

Added `$this->load->model('centers_model','',TRUE);` and the code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You get a blank page because there's a 500 internal error (most likely DB related issues). Check your php logs for errors, make sure that the table actually exists.

PS: You put the wrong filenames for each code. the model filenames look switched.

Comment: Most default environments will give a blank page when a 500 server error is encountered instead of printing errors on the page. Errors are suppressed and only written in a log file.

Comment: Yes, I've checked it... It's 500 internal server error. And also, I made a mistake here about the model file names. I've edited now. The table exists and I've fetched data from it in other other controllers and models. Also, why are the groups displayed but not the centers? Can't two models be loaded from a single controller function?

Comment: Did you fix the 500 server error and uncomment the line in the controller with $data["allcenters"]  ?

Comment: I do not know how to fix the 500 server error. If I uncomment the line, I'm getting the same error. 
If I comment it, the page loads good.
What might be the problem so that I could fix the 500 server error?

Comment: could you share the logs containing the php error ? without the actual logs no one can help you

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm a newbie. Could you please tell me how to view the php.ini file? I don't have cPanel and root access. 

My hosting server is from net4india and I accept that it is a shitty one.

Is there any other way to view php error logs?

https://imgur.com/a/hyh1W

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154014/discussion-between-balaji-kartheeswaran-and-bogdan-perian).